# SwiftUI : aliases for Stack or Group

Tags: swiftui, stack, alias, group

In order for me to better handle large bodies in Views (swiftUI) , i would like to rename/use some kind of alias for Group{} an/or Stack .I m looking to alias those elements, not to create additional subviews because it would add extra layer of communication between main view and sub views .
So instead of Group{}, Group{},Group{}, I m looking for Group1{},Group2{} ..
Thank you

Make code more readable

Comment: You might be able to use typealias to provide alternate names but I would suggest a better solution is to avoid large bodies by using separate views or helper methods to break the code up and make it easier to work with.

Comment: Hello , than for the answser , you said i might use typealias for this . How to do it for a keyword /@frozen element ?

Comment: `typealias Group1 = Group` etc. seems to work

Comment: Tried to use aliases for keyword without any success but it seems to work with containers indeed . Can you please make it an answer in order for me to accept it and upvote ? Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typealias Group1 = Group` etc. seems to work but I strongly recommend breaking your view into separate view structs and/or use helper methods to move some of the views to separate functions. It would make your code much more readable and easier to understand.